# Extract the code into an executable file vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

For example i have this code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim i As String
        i = xx
        MsgBox(i)
    End Sub
```

i want to make this code in exe file when click button in runtime

Comment: Can you expand on what you want to do. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. The code in your Form1 will produce a exe if you created a WPF or windows form application project

Comment: i want edit i from xx to yy and bulid this code in exe file in runtime when click on button

Comment: It is possible to generate an exe or dll using CodeDomProvider but if your goal is to edit a numeric value or a simple parameter, you should use the Settings in the projects properties.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using VB.Net. Just click on the Debug button. Or F5 button to debug it.
Also, your string should include quotes like "xx".

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers said, Visual Studio will automatically build an executable file for you. This happens when you debug or build your app. Press F5 to debug/run or build your application by right clicking your application in the solution explorer and selecting "build". This will create a .exe in the Debug folder of your Application. To find it, right click your application in the solution explorer and select open folder in file explorer. This will take you to the root folder of your application. Once there open "bin' then "debug" then run the file with your application name as its title and that ends in .exe(myapplication\bin\debug\myapplication.exe).

Comment: i want for example

Comment: the user write text in textbox when click on button make exe file . and when user open this exe file show masege

Comment: You want to dynamically create the .exes with random data. That is not what you wrote in your question. Please update your question. Include more info to increase your chances of getting a helpful answer.